# how to calculate sum of squares separately for a regression

Tags: r

I´m trying to understand all the formulas around regression and am trying to calculate basically sum(xi-mean(x))^2 for a dataset.
Tried this:

```
sum(pubs$pubs-mean(pubs$pubs))^2
```

Comment: output is 0  that´s  the problem

Comment: No, get a normal graph
if I calculate variance `sum((pubs$pubs-mean(pubs$pubs))^2/7)`
is works perfectly fine

Comment: alright, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you do the square first before summing, eg `sum((y - yhat)^2)`; otherwise, you should get zero because `mean(x) = sum(x)/n` and `sum(x-mean(x)) = sum(x) - n*mean(x)`.